# What does "name" mean in Django-url?

Tags: python, django

I was wondering, when using the url (`from django.conf.urls import url)`, what does `name = 'insert-something'` mean? For example, when making a url for registering a new user:

```
url(r'^register', views.register, name='register')
```

What does name='register' mean here? Why is it necessary?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use that name with `reverse` [LINK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: Your url address may change anytime, so instead of writing hard code url in template tag, you can simply write:
           {`% url 'register' %}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The name is used for accessingg that url from your Django / Python code. For example you have this in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^main/', views.main, name='main')
```

Now everytime you want to redirect to main page, you can say

```
redirect('app.main')
```

where `app` is the name of the django-app in which main is located. Or you can even use it for links in your html templates like

```
<a href="{% url 'app.main' %}">Go to main</a>
```

and this would link you to `www.example.com/main` for example. You could of course do

```
redirect('http://www.example.com/main')
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/main">Go to main</a>
```

respectively, but for example you want to change either domain or `main/` route. If all urls would be hardcoded in your project, then you would have to change it in every place. But if you used url `name` attribute instead, you can just change the url pattern in your `urls.py`.